# mod_rewrite to display simpler URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want this location on my website:

http://www.mywebsite.com/Facilities/Fishing/

to display to the user as this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/Fishing

I also want users to be able to visit that (http://www.mywebsite.com/Fishing) URL, and be redirected (internally only) to (http://www.mywebsite.com/Facilities/Fishing/) WHILE being shown the (http://www.mywebsite.com/Fishing) URL.

Basically I don't want the user to ever see that directory, even though it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Using RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^Fishing/?$ /Facilities/Fishing/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: hmmm, doesn't seem to be working for me. Perhaps I meant the inverse of this? I would like the URL to hide the "/Facilities" dir from the visitor.

Comment: @realcheesypizza: I thought you want to rewrite `http://www.mywebsite.com/Fishing` as `http://www.mywebsite.com/Facilities/Fishing/`.

Comment: I want the opposite of that actually, sorry if i was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^Facilities/Fishing/?$ /Fishing/ [L]
```

This chops off the `Facilities` bits.

Comment: Yeah that definitely seems correct, but im getting a 404 error. I guess something is not enabled? But i tested that mod-rewrite IS enabled, and it did pass. Sigh, Im still looking...thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the link directly to http://www.mywebsite.com/Fishing/ work? Or is it http://www.mywebsite.com/Fishing? (notice one has the slash at the end, and the other doesn't, even if the slash isn't displayed by SO)

Comment: Yes it does. I can do redirection just fine, but actually showing the simpler URL is what i can't achieve.

Comment: Wait a sec: you want the user to type in http://mywebsite.com/Fishing, and be redirected internally to http://mywebstie.com/Facilities/Fishing? If that's the case then @Selinap's solution is what you want. I'd remove the `R=301` and `NC` bits, but that should do what you want.

Comment: That is what i want, BUT to also have the "Facilities/" directory hidden from the user. With @Selinap's solution, I can still see that unwanted directory.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't in your question. Use @selinap's solution and then add `RewriteRule ^Facilities(.*)?$ - [R=404]` which will return a *not found* error for anything that asks for `Facilities` directly.